# How do we actually register a customised formatter in react vega?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I have read the documentation so many times https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/config.html#custom-format-type. I still don't understand how to implement this in react vega. What confuses me the most is this `vega` object.

```
view = new vega.View(...);
view.expressionFunction('customFormatA', function(datum, params) {
  ...
  return "<formatted string>";
});
```

What I am currently doing in React:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createClassFromSpec } from "react-vega";

const spec = {}

const BarChart = createClassFromSpec({ mode: "vega-lite", spec: spec });

export default function TestPage2({ data }) {
  return <BarChart data={{ table: data }} />;
}
```

Is there any example of implementing a custom format type that I can learn from?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? I'm trying to do the same in Vue.

Comment: No I have not found the answer anywhere on the web...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an error in the documentation and a [pull request](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/pull/6872) has been submitted.

You should use `vega` instead of `vega.View` like so:

```
import { expressionFunction } from 'vega';
expressionFunction('customFormatA', function(datum, params) {
  return datum;
});
```

However, note that custom formats do not work with binning; [an issue](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/6874) has been opened for this.